# AdHoc Phonegap iOS Testflight fails download when generated in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, provisioning, testflight

Phonegap 2.0* seems to have issues releasing thru ad hoc and testflightapp.com
I've created my ad hoc certs and mobile provision profiles and have gone thru all the necessary steps of archiving and distributing using proper bundle identifiers.

I tested this by creating a blank phonegap app
create /path build.identifier appname

open up xcode project file and change only the release code signing profile,

I generate the IPA and upload thru testflightapp.com, at about 90% the install bar, the app reads "Unable to download application" Cannot download at this time.

I create a blank single view project in xcode and use the same bundle identifier/release profile the app successfully uploads and installs thru testflight.

If I upload my app to build.phonegap.com and use them to generate the IPA it successfully downloads and installs, however I cannot customize icon/splash screens and other settings thru this method.

Has anyone successfully generated and distributed an IOS/Phonegap app thru testflight generated thru xcode? What steps am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

cordova version, version 2.X of cordova framework supports iOS6....
i was had the same issue, was using an old version of cordova (1.9) and when upgraded the issue went away